# A 250 GB HDD stuck with one 180 GB partition

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bootcamp, partition

I have a 250 GB hard drive in my MacBook Pro, I used to have a 70 GB BootCamp partition installed, leaving the Mac partition to 180 GB.
Now I no longer need to have BootCamp, so I deleted it using a Ubuntu live CD.
The reason I did it this way was because after upgrading to Mavericks, OS X no longer recognised my BootCamp partition for some reason.

But after deleting the partition, my Mac partition got stuck on 180 GB, with no possibility to make it 240 GB (excluding the EFI and recovery partitions).
This is my current:

```
Last login: Sat Jun 15 00:55:02 on console
MacBookPro:~ auser$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            179.6 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s4
MacBookPro:~ auser$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem now.
All I had to do, is the following, in the right order:

```
1. Go to Disk Utility > 250.06 GB Hitachi HTblablabla > Partition.
2. Click on "Recovery HD".
3. Click +.
4. Click - on the newly created partition.
5. Click - on the Recovery HD, which suddenly jumped from 650 MB to 62 GB.
6. Resize "Macintosh HD" to 249,72 GB.
7. Click "Apply".
```

PS: it takes a hell lot of time to finish the process.